# joins question - getting millions of rows, expected 45k

Tags: mysql, join

I wrote the following code. I'm expecting a result set of 45k, but am getting millions of rows in the visual explain. I want all salesforce_ids from salesforce_contacts (so that is the base) and then to join on if they exist in the other tables. I am not sure where the error is. Can anyone help?

```
use leeds_new; 

select 

sc.salesforce_id, 
sc.ethnicity,
sc.gender,
sc.person_of_color,
sc.lgbtq,
sc.veteran,
sc.first_generation_american,
sc.first_generation_college_going,
sc.low_income_background,
sc.is_parent,
sc.is_teacher,
sc.ladder_engagement,
sc.ladder_advocacy,
sc.ladder_elected,
sc.ladder_policy,
sc.ladder_organizing,
sc.ladder_collective,
sc.contact_in_ri_supported_region,
ar.`name` as alumni_region,
min(nw.date_end) as first_nw,
min(rt.date_end) as first_rt,
rt.track_type,
min(cf.date_end) as first_cf,
cf.fellowship_type,
cf.subtrack,
min(cr.date_start) as first_cr, 
cr.coaching_status




from salesforce_contacts sc
inner join leeds_new.salesforce_alumni_regions_federated as ar on sc.alumni_region_id = ar.alumni_region_id
left join leenk_national_workshops as nw on sc.salesforce_id = nw.member_id
left join leenk_regional_trainings as rt on sc.salesforce_id = rt.member_id
left join leenk_cohorts_fellowships as cf on sc.salesforce_id = cf.member_id
left join leenk_coaching_relationships as cr on sc.salesforce_id = cr.member_id 

group by sc.salesforce_id;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to find **only** those ids that exist in all the tables? if so you should use `join` instead of `left join`

Comment: You might have many-to-many relationships somewhere in your joins. Please post table structures, sample data and expected output, then we will really be in a position to help.

Comment: I want all the IDs that exist in salesfoce_contacts, and then: 

min(nw.date_end) as first_nw,
min(rt.date_end) as first_rt,
rt.track_type,
min(cf.date_end) as first_cf,
cf.fellowship_type,
cf.subtrack,
min(cr.date_start) as first_cr, 
cr.coaching_status

If the IDs exist in the related tables

Comment: I suggest you build the query up, join by join, until the unexpected bit occurs